# How can I use value of onscreenclick(func) event outside func?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Using Turtle, I want to be able to make a variable that contains the position on the screen that the user clicked.

I've found that it's possible to print the location of a click using the following code:

```
import turtle

def find_click_pos(x, y):
    print('{0}, {1}'.format(x, y))

def main():
    turtle.onscreenclick(find_click_pos)

main()

turtle.mainloop()
```

The problem with this is that the `x, y` co-ordinates are only defined in the `find_click_pos` function, and as far as I know there's no way to use them elsewhere in the function without using global variables (which I'd like to avoid at all costs).

Is there any way to get the value of `.onscreenclick()` without sending it to a function? Is there any other function of `turtle` that does what I want that I'm missing?

Comment: Does `click_position = turtle.onscreenclick(find_click_pos)` work?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `x` and `y` values?

Comment: @glhr so that the main() function can know where the user clicks on the turtle window

Comment: @Recessive doing this always seems to return `None`

Comment: Ah, that's because in the `find_click_pos(x, y)` you are just printing the position. Try replacing the line `print('{0}, {1}'.format(x, y))` with `return '{0}, {1}'.format(x, y)` and then you should be able to use `click_position = turtle.onscreenclick(find_click_pos)` as expected. That way in main (where I'm guessing all your code is) you can get the click pos.

Comment: @Recessive, your suggestion won't work.  The `turtle.onscreenclick()` function simply sets a handler function and always returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

The callback function you pass to `onscreenclick` can do whatever it wants with the `x` and `y` values it gets called with. It's not really clear what you want to do, but it's pretty hard to imagine that you can't find a way to do it in a function.

If you're concerned about how you can pass the values around without using global variables, perhaps the best way would be to have the callback be a method in a class, so that it can assign attributes that other methods can easily read:

```
import turtle

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.click_x = 0  # initialize with dummy values
        self.click_y = 0
        turtle.ontimer(self.other_method, 1000)

    def click_cb(self, x, y):
        self.click_x = x
        self.click_y = y

    def other_method(self):
        print(self.click_x, self.click_y)
        turtle.ontimer(self.other_method, 1000)

foo = Foo()
turtle.onscreenclick(foo.click_cb)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems the wrong thing to do.  I like @Blckknght's object-based solution (+1) but you'd just be substituting a *global variable* containing an object instance for a *global variable* containg a position.

If you really want to do the wrong thing, and avoid a global variable, you might as well do it the wrong way -- and what can be more wrong than a dangerous default value:

```
import turtle

def get_click_position(x=None, y=None, stash=[0, 0]):  # dangerous default value
    if x != None != y:
        stash[0:] = (x, y)

    return turtle.Vec2D(*stash)

def print_click_position():
    x, y = get_click_position()
    print('{0}, {1}'.format(x, y))

    turtle.ontimer(print_click_position, 1000)

turtle.onscreenclick(get_click_position)
print_click_position()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Call `get_click_position()` with no arguments if you want to know what the last click occured.  It will keep returning that result until a new click comes in, at which time `get_click_position()` is invoked as an event handler with arguments.

Comment: Do you think that it's best to use a global variable in this case? I was under the  impression that it's always best to avoid them.

Comment: @Gondamar, I think it's best to avoid making too many arbitrary constraints when asking for help.  You don't explain why you can't work within the event-based paradigm *and* insist you can't have global variables.  Explain more about what you're trying to do, and include more code, if you want help that really fits your need.